# how to add IIRF Redirect rule

Tags: url-rewriting, iirf

Hi
I've installed IIRF but everytime i add a rule it doesn't redirect me.
My site address looks like this
www.domain.com/Apps/WW/Page.aspx?ws=8888888&page=9999999
I want it to look like this
www.domain.com/888888/999999

Can you tell me which rule do i need to add?
I've installed the IIRF correctly, the iirfstatus page shows that everything was installed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /Apps/WW/Page.aspx?ws=$1&page=$2 [I,L]
```